# Hover Message in html on a button

Tags: html, web, hover

How to get hover message when mouse goes on a button.

Thanks

Comment: Use the `title` attribute.

Comment: See my answer? Its right in there.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a title attribute.

```
<input type='button'  value='Press me' title='This is my title' />
```

Comment: `title` is an attribute. `input` is the tag.

Comment: @CodyGray what if i want to show some value stored in a variable $count in the title. like "23 reg left" on hover. where $ count = 23

Comment: @rachel `title="<?php echo $count . "reg left" ; ?>"`

Answer (score 1):

The attribute title matters here. Just add the title attribute and write the message to be given in button tag.

example :

```
<button title="Message needs to be shown">My button</button>
```

This should work fine. if you are using link for the button:

```
<button><a href="http://link.php" title="Msg to be shown">My button</a></button>
```